# Reload same page several times in Blogger/Blogspot will reduce bounce rate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, blogger, blogspot

I'm trying to make a simple pagination in Blogger with Javascript. The idea is hiding the second paragraph, and show it when we click a button (and hide the first paragraph when we do so). The page will also be reloaded everytime the button clicked.

So, if my visitor reload the same page for several times, will it improve the bounce rate? Since it's the same URL.

It's a bit different with other self-hosted blog because they have different URL for each page. Something like:

> domain.com/the-title?page=2
>  domain.com/the-title?page=3
>   domain.com/the-title?page=4

...etc

Also, will it affect the SEO? Is everything I hid in second paragraph will be invisible in Google search result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. Let me explain the reasons why:

1.The bounce rate is increased when a user visits your page and leaves without interacting with your site / visiting another page.

2.Refreshing the page does not start a new session/pageview. No matter how many times they visit your site they will re-open the exact same session for 30mins.

3.Javascript refresh or meta refresh does not count as user interaction. You may also want to read more about Google and Javascripts. Google can read your content even if you use javascript or refresh for Dynamic content.
 (http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

4.Hiding any texts from the user is never a good idea. You may apply it in times that you need specific KPIs for clicks of buttons or cases like that but... can't you just use heatmaps or even better seperate content? Anyway, if you use it on a high percent of your content you might have Cloaking problems.(https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355)

So it will not affect your bounce rate. You might get cloaking warning if you apply this on the majority of your website. It might also be considered a problematic user experience and lower your techincal seo scores (page load times etc.). As you can see you might only get problems by using such methods. I would suggest you to not proceed with the idea.

Comment: I don't understand, session is calculated every 30 minutes? How if i use Wordpress, divide it into 4 pages, and visitors finish reading the entire article within 10 minutes? Is it counted as 1 session? Or 4 according to the page count?

Comment: I said refreshing or revisiting a page reopens the existing session. The same user ID will reopen the same session if he/she visited the page again in the past 30 mins. So if you make two separate visits and do/choose different actions in the same page. The analytics will only show one session were he/she did both of those things. It will not consider it as separate visits.

Comment: Please check the following link where Google explains the 30 minutes session and how it works. (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en)

Comment: Igniel do you have any more questions for the topic?